# Origin of Chatur-Bhuja forms of deities

Tags: gods

I would like to trace the origin of the chatur-bhuja representation of the deities in Hinduism. Many deities in Hinduism are portrayed with four hands - almost all the deities appear in this form (though there are some deity specific representations). I want to trace some earliest writings / notes in our scriptures to this form of The Gods.

I am specifically looking for

1. Any unambiguous Vedic references (anywhere in The Vedas) mentioning Chaturbhuja form of any deity
2. Published research articles that shine some light on this form / representation

Considering the nature of the question, there is no single right or wrong answer. I am seeking facts (in the form of published references) as opposed to personal opinions and beliefs. To that effect please quote the sources to help me establish traceability.

Thanks in advance.